# Why would Jenkins pipeline simple sh keeps hanging

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to run my builder docker image as non-root for two days now, however I am facing all kinds of problem. The simplest form of the problem I am facing is if I want to run this pipeline, my jenkins build will keep hanging:

```
node('') {
    stage ('test') {
        withDockerContainer(image: 'openjdk:8-jdk', args: '-u 1000', toolName: env.DOCKER_TOOL_NAME) {
            sh 'amir'
        }
    }
}
```

this is the jenkins output:
[image: The build keeps hanging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating more on the issue and reading through https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf (in summary, the blog is saying it's uid and gid that's important and not the username), I decided to change my approach not to run with '-u 1000' but without specifying user and instead building my image with the same uid and gid as the jenkins which is building.
In other words, now my pipeline:
Builds a docker image passing the jenkins uid and gid as docker build param
Dockerfile:

```
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

RUN groupadd -g ${GID} $RUNNER_USER
RUN useradd -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -ms /bin/bash $RUNNER_USER
```

my jenkins pipeline docker build part:

```
docker.build("$dockerImage", '--build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) .')
```

Running build on the built docker image:

```
withDockerContainer(image: dockerImage, args: '--net="host"', toolName: env.DOCKER_TOOL_NAME) {
    // do the build, e.x. sh "mvn clean package"
}
```